# Multiple TableViews in a single screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UIViewController that I plan to have two TableViews and some other items in.
Both TableViews I am using on other screens, so I want to make them as independent and reusable as possible. One of those TableViews is called messageList (A UITableView) which shows my ChatHistory.

I am trying to understand if my approach is. [Edited 9/2 with correct code to make this approach work]

One approach would be to use a single table with 2 different sections, then in the delegate methods use a conditional statement to see which section is which and act accordingly.

The problem with this approach is usability. I want to easily reuse my TableViews in other views where one or the other TableView may or may not exist. Additionally, I want the DataSource to exist throughout the lifecycle of the app regardless of what Controller is instantiated or active.

My approach is to separate the view controller that manages the table view's from the table UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate implementations. But I am having a problem making this work.

Focusing on one of the TableViews, my ChatTableView.

In my AppDelegate has a property for chatHistory of type ChatHistory which implements UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource.

// AppDelegate.h

```
ChatHistory *chatHistory;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) ChatHistory *chatHistory;
```

//  ChatHistory.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ChatHistory : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    UITableViewCell *nibLoadedCell;
    NSMutableArray *messages;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewCell   *nibLoadedCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray    *messages;

@end
```

//  ChatHistory.m - Note this code, including the custom cell was working correctly when it was a part of the controller so I believe it should be correct

```
#import "ChatHistory.h"
#include "ChatMessage.h"

@implementation ChatHistory
@synthesize nibLoadedCell;   // custom cell design
@synthesize messages;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [messages count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Discussion"];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = nibLoadedCell;
    }
    // custom tag order - username; message; future - Avatar; like; dislike
ChatMessage *obj = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UILabel *messageLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
messageLabel.text = obj.message;
UILabel *usernameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
usernameLabel.text = obj.sender;
return cell;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    if (messages) [messages release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

// MyViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   // MAKE SURE TO INITIALIZE viewDidLoad not InitWithNib
        if (!appDelegate.chatHistory)
                appDelegate.chatHistory = [[ChatHistory alloc] init];

        messageList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 54, 320, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        messageList.dataSource = appDelegate.chatHistory;
        messageList.delegate = appDelegate.chatHistory;
        [self.view addSubview:messageList];
        ...
```

Comment: Note: I successfully got my approach to work in a test project. I will try to reintegrate it back into my original project and share what I find. Thank you Felix and AndrewS for affirming the singleton approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one central data store, you could create a [`Singleton`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class with the data.
Then set it as the data source for the table view or fetch the array (or whatever you got) from the data store in your `UIViewController` / `UITableViewController`.

If you initialize the data store in your `AppDelegate`, you can access it from every class you want (note that all data you load, will remain in memory until your application gets terminated by iOS)

[How to create a Singleton class in Objective-C](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/)

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I am doing. The only difference, is that I have combined my datasource object and my view protocols. I have set the datasource here messageList.dataSource = appDelegate.chatHistory;. Currently the data is InMemory and will likely stay that way. I just need to populate that data regardless of what controller is in control. I initialize the DataStore the first time it is used.  My current problem is really more about wanting to put the Delegate in it's own class. And for some reason, while all of the docs I have read say that should be ok. It is not working.

Comment: I found out why it was not working and am updating the code. Essentially I needed to instantiate the view in ViewDidLoad not initFromNib where the self.view was not initialized yet. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to make a view controller your tableview DataSource or delegate; any object can be set. You can use a singleton as Felix suggests, or any other class structure you want. Since you mention that you want the chat history to be available from anywhere in the app, it makes sense to provide a UITableViewDataSource protocol to that chat history.

As for the UITableViewDelegate, you can simply create a new class as a subclass of NSObject and implement the delegate there. Make sure it's created and retained properly, and set in (upon load) as the delegate for your table views.

Comment: Tx Andrew, that is essentially what I have done, but the code above is not working. It is crashing in MyViewController at [self.view addSubview:messageList];  ChatHistory is acting as my delegate and DataSource right now. It implements both UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. It is a subclass of NSObject. Above I show the code on how I create it in InitWithNib. I appreciate the time everyone. I'm a bit dumbfounded as to why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way: make the two `UITableView`s subviews of one view controller.

In **each** of the `datasource` methods you simply distinguish between the two tables, similar to the code Apple provides in the `UISearchDisplayController` examples. For instance:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  if (tableView == myTableView1) {
    // return appropriate number of rows
  }
  // return appropriate number of rows for the other table view
}
```

I know this does not separate the two table view classes very neatly. You would have to have a view controller controlling **two** other view controllers, one for each tableview.

Perhaps one has to consider the tradeoff between reusability and the complications of a more convoluted architecture (which typically also leads to classes that do not perform all that well in terms of reusability). That's why I would recommend the approach from the Apple sample projects.

Comment: Interesting. I actually see my code as less complicated or convoluted.  Do you see any reason why my code should not work?

Comment: Actually, if I have one view controller with subviews, I find it easier to have this controller control all its subviews. I remarked that not your code is convoluted, but your architecture.

Comment: My architecture is that multiple controllers host a common subView. My controller does control all of it's subViews. I simply reuse subViews in multiple screens/controller. On one screen (one controller), there are two subViews a chat box and a list of items. On another screen (diff controller), just the chat box exists. On another screen (diff controller) just the list of items exists. If I am thinking about this wrong, I would love to correct my thinking. Thanks Mundi.